# Дробные числа в бд

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Когда я отправляю дробное число вида `"1234.56"` в базу (формат данных `INT`), оно становится `1235`. Подскажите, что нужно поменять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого предусмотрены специальные типы данных float, double...
Конкретно в вашем случае скорее всего более подходит тип **float**

Answer (score 1):

Почитать вот тут: [типы данных столбцов](http://mysql.ru/docs/man/Column_types.html).

Answer (score -2):

Смените int, к примеру, на varchar. :)

Comment: На float надо менять, а не на varchar... В крайнем случае, на double (если в этом есть смысл, естественно).

Comment: ну я не зря дал ссыль, там все описано)

Comment: **Palmervan** вы это мне?О_о

Comment: AlexWindHope к стате вспомнил ржаку, когда только начинал работать с php и mysql ставил на поле varchar ограничене 30 и записывал туда пароль в md5. 2 часа ламал голову почему я немогу войти под логином)))

Comment: У меня и не такое было :) я помню когдато не знал лькуда у меня берутся странные кавычки в html страничке... разобрался спустя 2 дня когда начал <b>учить</b>(дада, я реально настолько опечалился что начал учить, причем учил даже историю :)), ну так вот причина была utf + bom.. Теперь я этот bom зпомнил на всю оставшуюсь жизнь :) Сколько мне нервов испортила когдато, ужс...<br>
<small>PS:сорри за оффтоп :)</small>